# Problem when fetching json data from internet in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and was running a code to fetch and display data from internet. But when I'm running the code I'm getting this error:
`List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>`.
I tried to find out the solution but nothing is of help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Message extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessageState createState() => _MessageState();
}

class _MessageState extends State<Message> {
  Map data;
  List userData;
  Future getData() async
  {
    http.Response response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

    data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
     userData = data["data"];
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child:ListView.builder
          (
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
              itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
                return Row(
                  children:<Widget>[

                Text('${userData[index]["username"]}', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20),),
                Text('${userData[index]["catchPhrase"]}',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 17),),
                Icon(Icons.navigate_next)
                  ]
                  );
                   }

          )
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: please post your full json string get from api

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is that `data["data"]` is a Map and not a List.
Try changing the type to Map as said on your error log.

Can your please try the following?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Message extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessageState createState() => _MessageState();
}

class _MessageState extends State<Message> {
  Map data;
  Map<String, dynamic> userData;
  Future getData() async
  {
    http.Response response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

    data = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
     userData = data["data"];
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child:ListView.builder
          (
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: userData == null ? 0 : userData.length,
              itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
                return Row(
                  children:<Widget>[
                    Text('${userData[userData.keys.toList()[index]]["username"]}', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20),),
                    Text('${userData[userData.keys.toList()[index]]["catchPhrase"]}',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 17),),
                    Icon(Icons.navigate_next)
                  ]);
              }

          )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it :

1. Define a model class.
2. Define .fromJson method
3. Fetch the data
4. Pass the data to the model, create instance and make a list.

Example :

Model :

```
class User {
final int id;
...

User({
@required this.id
...
})

User.fromJson(Map json)
: this.id = json["id"]
...
```

And you use this model in the network call as follows :

```
Map<String, dynamic> response = await http.get(...)


List<User> users = (response as List)
    .map((element) => User.fromJson(element))
    .toList();
```

*P.S. : I wrote this code directly in SO (It is not unit tested. You might have to do little tweak to make it work)*